# Calculating $[H,\vec r]$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, vector-fields

I'm doing Griffiths' Introduction to Quantum Mechanics. In a question, it introduces the modified Schrodinger equation in which the Hamiltonian, $$ H~=~-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2 + V $$is replaced by the classical Hamiltonian, $$ H~=~\left[\frac{1}{2m}(\frac{\hbar}{i}\nabla-q\vec {\mathbf A})^2 +q\phi\right]$$ which I expanded out to $$ H= \left[ \frac{1}{2m}\left\{-\hbar^2\nabla^2+q^2A^2+i\hbar q(\vec\nabla\cdot\vec {\mathbf A}+\vec {\mathbf A}\cdot\vec \nabla)\right \}+q\phi \right]$$

Here $\vec{\mathbf A}$ is the vector potential for the magnetic field $(\vec{\mathbf B}=\vec\nabla \times\vec{\mathbf A}) $ and $\phi$ is the scalar potential for the electric field $(\vec{\mathbf E}=-\nabla\phi-\frac{\partial\vec{\mathbf A}}{\partial t})$.

Now the first part of the question requires one to calculate $[H,\vec {\mathbf r}]$. But that requires me to take the Laplacian of $ \vec {\mathbf r}\psi$ which is a vector function (due to the first term in the expression). Is this legal?

I know that one way around this is to work component wise. But how to make this work?

Comment: Without expanding the Hamiltonian, use $[A^2,B]= A[A,B]+ [A,B]A$ and CCRs. Notice also  that $\vec{r}$ commutes with both $\vec{A}$ and $\phi$...

Comment: Canonical commutation relations $[p_j, r_k]= -i\hbar \delta_{jk}I$, where $p_j = -i\hbar \nabla_j$.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Yeah, realized that.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Yes, but how to set this right?

Comment: I do not understand well your problem. However work in components...

Comment: @ValterMoretti I mean to ask is there a way (maybe using more math) of making this approach work. With tensors perhaps...?

Comment: @Anonymous_original As already suggested you need not really represent the momentum operator as Laplacian: the Hamiltonian is of the form $H=(p-qA)^2 + V$, therefore the commutator can be expanded as function of $[x,p]$ and $[x, A], [x, V]$.

Comment: @gented I understand that. But I'm curious about the consistency of the two approaches, which is why I feel there must be some way to get the result by the Laplacian method too. I want to know about that.

Comment: @Anonymous_original Well then just take derivatives of the coordinates: what in particular is puzzling you about the "brute force" approach? Remember that $[H, \textbf{r}]$ is just shorthand notation for the collection of $[H,x], [H, y], [H, z]$ so just calculate each piece one by one.

Comment: @gented I'm working in spherical polar coordinates. So then I can't take $\hat r$ outside the commutator. What to do then?

Comment: @Anonymous_original Is there any particular reason why you are choosing spherical coordinates? I still don't understand why you want to make it so hard for yourself when the statement can really be proven in a few lines (maybe not a few, but conceptually few).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem (as I understand it) boils down to calculating the [vector Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Laplacian) for the vector field function $\mathbf{r} \psi$.  This calculation can be performed in any coordinate system you choose;  if you know how to apply divergences, gradients, and curls to an arbitrary vector field in that coordinate system, then the identity
$$
\nabla^2 \mathbf{A} \equiv \nabla \left( \nabla \cdot \mathbf{A} \right) - \nabla \times \left( \nabla \times \mathbf{A} \right)
$$
allows for the calculation of the vector Laplacian.

In Cartesian components, this reduces to the particularly nice
$$
\nabla^2 \mathbf{A} = \left( \nabla^2_s A_x \right) \hat{x} +  \left( \nabla^2_s A_y \right) \hat{y} + \left( \nabla^2_s A_z \right) \hat{z},  
$$
where $\nabla^2_s$ is the familiar "scalar Laplacian".  It should therefore be possible to calculate $\nabla^2 (\mathbf{r} \psi)$ by setting $A_x = x \psi$ in the above, and similarly for $A_y$ and $A_z$.  The result will then be expressible in terms of vectors and gradients, which you can then put back into a coordinate-invariant form and re-express in terms of spherical coordinates if you like.

Alternately, if you want to stay in spherical coordinates the whole time, you can use the above identity to express $\nabla^2 \mathbf{A}$ in terms of the spherical coordinates of $\mathbf{A}$.  In your case, you will have $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{r} \psi$, and so $A_r = r \psi$ while $A_\theta = A_\phi = 0$.  However, the vector Laplacian is not nearly as nice in spherical coordinates as it is in Cartesian coordinates;  if you want to see the full expression, it can be found in [this table on Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates#Del_formula)  When the dust settles, though, you should find an expression in terms of $\psi$, the spherical coordinates $\{r, \theta, \phi\}$, and the derivatives of the former with respect to the latter.

Both of the above methods are equivalent, and should yield the same result;  try them both out if you need to while away a rainy afternoon.  And, of course, both are equivalent to the method (suggested by gented in the comments) of expressing $H = \frac{1}{2m}(\mathbf{p} - q \mathbf{A})^2 + q \phi$ and using the canonical commutation relations $[x_i, x_j] = [p_i, p_j] = 0$, $[x_i, p_j] = \delta_{ij}$.  I suspect that after going through the Laplacian calculations above, you will appreciate the elegance of the operator method.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks. I do appreciate the methods suggested by others and will try to use them (whenever need be). It was just that I wanted to know how this particular approach would work (if needed in the future) for the sake of completeness.